# How to set up Serilog "Enrichers" in configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I set up Serilog in my NET 6 WebAPI app but it is not logging enrichers I set up in the Erich array below (in appsettings):

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "Enrich": [ "WithHttpRequestId", "WithExceptionDetails", "WithClientIp" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "../../../../../Logs/MyApp/MyApp-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": "7",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} {CorrelationId} {Level:u3}] {Username} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception} {Properties:lj}{NewLine}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I got the enricher names from [serilog's wiki](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment). The idea was to log the HTTPRequestId, ClientIp, and automagically log the details of every exception thrown (without having to do `_logger.LogError(...)`). However I don't see those details in the logs.
In Program.cs:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
  .Enrich.FromLogContext()
  .CreateLogger();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

Questions:

1. Is my setup correct? Especially my outputTemplate?
2. Are there Enrichers to log each request and response automatically including the body and paramters?
3. I set the file retention to 7 days as you can see. WHEN does Serliog delete the older files? When I restart the server in Visual Studio, I see that the older files get deleted. Does that mean files only get deleted on server restart while in production? Or does this cleanup run on regular intervals during runtime?

Comment: Have you added the enricher packages? [Serilog.AspNetCore](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) doesn't have any enrichers with such names. Where do these enrichers come from?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I updated the description with source.

Comment: I think you may be mistaken what enriches are or do. You do need to write a log message for it to be enriched. Just having enriches doesn't magically log stuff all by itself.